# make: *** No rule to make target `main.c', needed by `main.o'. Stop

Tags: c, unix, gnu-make

### functions.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_hello(void);
int factorial(int n);
```

### main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functions.h>
int main()
{
 print_hello();
 printf("\nThe factorial is: %d \n",factorial(5));
 return 0;
}
```

### hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functions.h>
void print_hello()
{
 printf("\nHello World!\n");
}
```

### factorial.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functions.h>
int factorial(int n)
{
 if(n!=1)
 {
  return(n*factorial(n-1));
 }
 else
  return 1;
}
```

### makefile

```
exec : \
 compile  
    echo "Executing the object file"
    ./compile 

compile : main.o hello.o factorial.o
    echo "Compiling"
    gcc -o compile $^

main.o : main.c functions.h
    gcc -c main.c -I./INCLUDE -I./SRC

hello.o : hello.c functions.h
    gcc -c hello.c -I./INCLUDE -I./SRC

factorial.o : factorial.c functions.h
    gcc -c factorial.c -I./INCLUDE -I./SRC
```

> Folder: make_example\INCLUDE\functions.h Folder:
>   make_example\SRC\main.c Folder: make_example\SRC\hello.c Folder:
>   make_example\SRC\factorial.c Folder: make_example\makefile

I'm getting an error when compiled the make file as "desktop:~/make_example$ make

make: *** No rule to make target `main.c', needed by`main.o'.  Stop."

Please help me understand why this error

Answer (score 11):

When you run `make` it tries to make the first target in the file (`exec`), which depends on `compile`, which depends on `main.o`, which depends on `main.c`. There is no file `main.c`, only `SRC/main.c`. There is no rule to make a file called `main.c`, and there is no pre-existing `main.c`, so `make` has an error and exits.

[You can fix this](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/make_4.html#SEC26) with `VPATH` or `vpath`:

```
VPATH = SRC INCLUDE
```

Comment: Thank u .. I tried but its showing me an error like this..gcc -s -c main.c SRC INCLUDE gcc: main.c: No such file or directory make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: Is it possible to set the path for the directory without using VPATH or vpath.Please help.

Comment: Instead of pleading help, try analyzing the problem. `make` found the file, but `gcc` didn't, so you have solved one error and surfaced the next. You should use `$<` instead of `main.c` in the compiler rule.

Answer (score 7):

Your main.c is in the subdirectory src, and make does not know to look there.  There are many options, the easiest of which is to write "src/main.c" instead of "main.c" in the makefile.  You could also move main.c up a level, or move the makefile to src/ and build there, or put a makefile in the toplevel that cds into src and calls that make (this is recursive make, which many consider "harmful", but is perfectly fine in many(most) cases.)  You can also use a VPATH directive, but if you choose to do so, be aware that this will not work with all versions of make.